# PHP curl exec fail on php script same domain

Tags: php, curl

I use php curl to get content from a php script in the same domain url. But I get curl_exec error. The curl error code is 28 or operation timed out. After days of debugging, I found that it works on non script page like htm, but not php, it also works if the url is a script on different domain. I have been debugging for days and found no solutions. Helps appreciated.

```
$url = 'http://...';
$agent = '';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 8);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 8);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
print "<pre>\n";
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
// get error info echo "\n\ncURL error number:" .curl_errno($ch);
// print error info echo "\n\ncURL error:" . curl_error($ch);
print "</pre>\n";
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
```

cURL error number:28 cURL error:

> Operation timed out after 8000
>   milliseconds with 0 bytes received

Okay: `$url = http://.../page.htm`
Fail: `$url = http://.../page.php`

Comment: Please show some code and if possible a real life code example of an URL that times out

Comment: Curl code:

$url = 'http://...';
$agent = '';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 8);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        8);

$result = curl_exec ($ch);

print "<pre>\n";
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));  // get error info
echo "\n\ncURL error number:" .curl_errno($ch); // print error info
echo "\n\ncURL error:" . curl_error($ch); 
print "</pre>\n";

curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;

Comment: cURL error number:28
cURL error:Operation timed out after 8000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

Okay: $url = http://../page.htm.
Fail: $url = http://.../page.php

Answer (score 7):

You're not setting the User Agent. Some servers actually do not even respond to such requests (thus the client doesn't know the connection dropped).

Add the following to your code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

Additionally, I use the following in my CURL functionality:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,50);
if(substr($url,0,8)=='https://'){
    // The following ensures SSL always works. A little detail:
    // SSL does two things at once:
    //  1. it encrypts communication
    //  2. it ensures the target party is who it claims to be.
    // In short, if the following code is allowed, CURL won't check if the 
    // certificate is known and valid, however, it still encrypts communication.
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH,CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
}
```

Comment: I face the same problem and `curl_getinfo` prints `array(37) { ["url"]=> string(40) "http://localhost:4000/public/server2.php" ["content_type"]=> NULL ["http_code"]=> int(0) ["header_size"]=> int(0) ["request_size"]=> int(0) ["filetime"]=> int(-1) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(0) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0) ["connect_time"]=> float(0) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["size_upload"]=> float(0) ["size_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_upload"]=> float(0) ["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["upload_content_len..

Comment: Regarding my comment from now, should I post a new question although it is similar to this. `cURL error number:0`. Curl from terminal works to the localhost address.

Comment: @Timo yes please, post a new question. Replies are not meant to as questions unless directly related to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because of session locks
Try to drop [session_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) from page which you try to get using cURL

Also see this [session.auto-start](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start)

Comment: Or do a `session_write_close()` before doing the curl_exec. The session can re-opened with `session_start()` after curl finishes, if anything in the session needs to be updated.

Comment: Did both session_start() and session_write_close() still fail.

Comment: Try to echo some thing simple in page.php (echo "foobar"), is it works now?

Comment: No, still timeout. Looks like curl exec doesn't like php script from same domain, other plain file is ok. Not sure why.

Comment: No no, I'll check this, every thing is OK for me

Comment: @MarcB I cannot up-vote your session_write_close()/session_start() tip enough! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Set into CURL setting

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300); // 300 seconds
```

If still have issue so run the script with following location disable.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
```