# PHP cURL post to same site returns 1, with no error, and no info and no actual post made

Tags: php, curl

I'm working on using cURL to pass paypal IPN data from our WooCommerce WordPress IPN responder to our ASP.NET based licensing code which resides on the same server.  I had this working before when the ASP.NET code was on another site, but when it came time to move them to the same server, it stopped working.  I've read:

[if curl getinfo for HTTP CODE is not returning a code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513073/if-curl-getinfo-for-http-code-is-not-returning-a-code)

[PHP curl exec fail on php script same domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128379/php-curl-exec-fail-on-php-script-same-domain)

[Can servers block curl requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391137/can-servers-block-curl-requests?rq=1)

[Can I do a CURL request to the same server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412069/can-i-do-a-curl-request-to-the-same-server)

I've tried the solutions and variations there of from each of these posts and have had no luck.

As stated in the title, the response from curl_exec is 1, curl_error, curl_errno, curl_getinfo are all empty.  Very hard to figure out what's going on without any details.

Here's my original code:

```
    //open connection
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url6);
//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($postdata));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post_string);

//execute post

$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

$url6 points a aspx page on the same server using a full http:// address and as I mentioned this code worked perfectly fine when pointed to another server.  This site is hosted on GoDaddy (not my choice) if that helps.

Been banging my head against this wall all day, could really use some insight here, thanks!

Comment: If you dump `$post_string` and `$postdata` are they exactly as they are supposed to be? I have a feeling those variables may not be filled the same as on the previous server.

Comment: the code that calls curl_exec hasn't moved servers at all, only the asp.net services have moved.  The only thing I changed in my code was the value of the url, that's it.

Comment: Oh. Can you try making that request manually from the server as-if you were cURL (since cURL apparently does not return any errors)? And second, are you using a `localhost` or other self-routed domain, or `127.0.0.1` or something else?

Comment: I assume that the versions of the old and new ASP.NET servers are the same or generally close?

Comment: Manual request is processed but runs into errors because the expected form post is not there.  No localhost or loop  backs.  ASP.NET servers are both set to 4.0 and both are GoDaddy hosted under the same account, so I'm assuming they're fairly close.